# Does any body knows the way to make a connection with websokets in a productive way with a SSL and Nginx?

Tags: nginx, websocket

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cD8l.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UdEr.png)

in a local way works but in a productive way is not working

what changes should I make to have have the websokets connection working in the right way?, is there something that it's important to take into acount? somebody already resolve the issue ?